# How do I dynamically access request parameters with JSP EL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I'm looping through a list of items, and I'd like to get a request parameter based on the item's index.
I could easily do it with a scriptlet as done below, but I'd like to use expression language.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" varStatus="count">

   <!-- This would work -->
   <%=request.getParameter("item_" + count.index)%>

   <!-- I'd like to make this work -->
   ${param.?????}

</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<c:set var="index" value="item_${count.index}" />
${param[index]}
```

Unfortunately, + doesn't work for strings like in plain Java, so

```
${param["index_" + count.index]}
```

doesn't work ;-(

Comment: i corrected the reference to params. it's supposed to be param. But your answer gave me what I needed to get it working. Thanks!

Comment: You can do something like this: ${param["index_".concat(count.index)]}

Answer (score 4):

There is a list of implicit objects in the [Expression Language documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043) section of the J2EE 1.4 documentation. You're looking for *param*.

Comment: Thanks I looked it up and realized I was accessing the wrong thing. The main thing I was missing was the bracket syntax for accessing a property.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the "square brackets" notation.  With the use of a JSTL <c:set> tag you can generate the correct parameter name:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" varStatus="count">
  <c:set var="paramName">item_${count.index}</c:set>
  ${param[paramName]}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:

```
${param.item_[count.index]}
```